# Ejabberd crashed after using Redis as cache

Tags: redis, erlang, ejabberd

I am building a push system based on Ejabberd, but having performance issue(4 nodes as the cluster, 400k users online) on MYSQL.

I tried to add Redis as the cahce system for Offline Messages/Broadcasting Messages. Everything goes well except when broadcasting starts.

It seemed to be a network issue, because I caught errors as followings:

1. Mnesia is overloaded: {mnesia_tm,message_queue_len,[24017,34957]}
2. mnesia_event got {inconsistent_database, running_partitioned_network
3. Unexpected info: {mnesia_tm,'ejabberd2@push204.com',{dirty_res,ok}}
4. Lots of timeouts from mysql(we still use mysql to store user info)
5. emulator Discarding message replaced from <0.18659.61> to <0.15551.115> in an old incarnation (1) of this node (2)
6. Even worse, one of the 4 ejabberd nodes was not responding and crashed.

Strategy for broadcasting is sending message to online users, and then cache offline user list to redis.
Peak messages could reach to 500k per 5 minutes(we statis the number in 5 mins)
Data in Redis is about 5GB. Total user number is about 7 million.
Redis client is [eredis-pool](https://github.com/hiroeorz/eredis_pool)(I wonder the issue may be caused by the redis client)

Is there anyone can give some suggestions on troubleshooting?